# How do I select rows in Excel based on logic?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to select entire rows based on rules.

For instance:

1. How would I select all the rows where column A is greater than 3?
2. How would I select all rows which *contain* a string in Column A (string could be anywhere in the cell)?

I plan to select rows based on rules and then copy them into a new sheet, deleting empty rows after that.

I was hoping to do this without using VBA.

Comment: Why not use a filter and copy the results?

Comment: Yep, a filter is exactly what you need. You can add conditions or use patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Excel's built-in Table functions.

1. Convert your data to an Excel Table `Insert>Table`
2. Add a helper column for your logic

   - For instance 1 `=IF([@ColumnA]>3,1,0)`
   - For instance 2 `=IF(TYPE([@ColumnA])=2,1,0)`
3. Filter your results in the helper column for either True (1) or False (0)
4. Copy if necessary (or just leave filtered).

No VBA necessary!

Comment: 1 and 2 can be done without a helper column as well.